# Cant save the data from excel to database in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am new to programming. I have uploaded an excel and wanted to save the data in to database. But i m getting various errors when i try to solve it by checking with stackoverflow. Here is my code

MY view:

```
def createSchool(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['excel']:
        localvar= kidDetailsForm(request.POST)

        myfile = request.FILES['excel']
        book = xlrd.open_workbook(myfile.name)
        sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)

        for r in range(1, sheet.nrows):
           if localvar.is_valid():  
                temp = localvar.save(commit = False)  
                temp.childname = sheet.cell(r,0).value
                temp.dob    = sheet.cell(r,1).value
                temp.sex    = sheet.cell(r,2).value 
                temp.save()
        return render(request, 'littleStar/createSchool.html')
    return render(request, 'littleStar/createSchool.html')
```

my form:

```
class kidDetailsForm(forms.Form):

    class Meta():
        model = kidDetails
        fields = ("childname","dob","sex")
```

my Model:

```
class kidDetails(models.Model):

    childname= models.CharField(max_length=245)

    sex = models.CharField(max_length=245)

    dob = models.DateField(max_length=245)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.childname
```

But when i print the form. i see required errors. Is there a way to bypass the form.

I would like to upload the excel and save the data to database. Any help would be great and much appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: try `forms.ModelForm` instead of `forms.Form`

Comment: I have done that without forms. Directly linking view to model. Thanks for the answer.